# Unused arguments in R error

Tags: r

I am new to R , I am trying to run example which is given in "rebmix-help pdf". It use galaxy dataset and here is the code

```
library(rebmix)
devAskNewPage(ask = TRUE)
data("galaxy")
write.table(galaxy, file = "galaxy.txt", sep = "\t",eol = "\n", row.names = FALSE,    col.names = FALSE)
REBMIX <- array(list(NULL), c(3, 3, 3))
Table <- NULL
Preprocessing <- c("histogram", "Parzen window", "k-nearest neighbour")
InformationCriterion <- c("AIC", "BIC", "CLC")
pdf <- c("normal", "lognormal", "Weibull")
K <- list(7:20, 7:20, 2:10)
for (i in 1:3) {
for (j in 1:3) {
for (k in 1:3) {
REBMIX[[i, j, k]] <- REBMIX(Dataset = "galaxy.txt",
Preprocessing = Preprocessing[k], D = 0.0025,
cmax = 12, InformationCriterion = InformationCriterion[j],
pdf = pdf[i], K = K[[k]])
if (is.null(Table))
Table <- REBMIX[[i, j, k]]$summary
else Table <- merge(Table, REBMIX[[i, j,k]]$summary, all = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
    }
 }
}
```

It is giving me error ERROR:
unused argument (InformationCriterion = InformationCriterion[j])
Plz help

Comment: To clarify: that type of error message means there's a named argument which doesn't match anything in the "guts" of the function.  That's a pretty strong hint as to where a typo exists :-)

Comment: It looks like the rebmix package has been updated substantially since the example in the OP was written. There is also an updated demo using the galaxy data: `demo("rebmix.galaxy")`

Answer (score 0):

I'm running R 3.0.2 (Windows) and the library rebmix defines a function REBMIX where InformationCriterion is not listed as a named argument, but **Criterion**.

Brief invoke REBMIX as :

```
REBMIX[[i, j, k]] <- REBMIX(Dataset = "galaxy.txt",
    Preprocessing = Preprocessing[k], D = 0.0025,
    cmax = 12, Criterion = InformationCriterion[j],
    pdf = pdf[i], K = K[[k]])
```

Comment: Hey thanks for reply. I corrected that. Now it is giving me error "'Dataset' list of data frames is requested!"

Comment: From here: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rebmix/rebmix.pdf , page 30) : 

`Dataset       a list of data frames of size nd containing d-dimensional datasets. Each of the d columns represents one random variable. Number of observations n equals the number of rows in the datasets`

Answer (score 0):

It looks as though there have been substantial changes to the `rebmix` package since the example mentioned in the OP was created. Among the most noticable changes is the use of S4 classes.

There's also an updated demo in the rebmix package using the `galaxy` data (see `demo("rebmix.galaxy")`)

To get the above example to produce results (*Note: I am not familiar with this package or the rebmix algorithm!!!*):

1. Change the argument to `Criterion` as mentioned by @Giupo
2. Use the S4 slot access operator `@` instead of `$`
3. Don't name the results object `REDMIX` because that's already the function name

```
library(rebmix)
data("galaxy")

## Don't re-name the REBMIX object!
myREBMIX <- array(list(NULL), c(3, 3, 3))
Table <- NULL
Preprocessing <- c("histogram", "Parzen window", "k-nearest neighbour")
InformationCriterion <- c("AIC", "BIC", "CLC")
pdf <- c("normal", "lognormal", "Weibull")
K <- list(7:20, 7:20, 2:10)

for (i in 1:3) {
  for (j in 1:3) {
    for (k in 1:3) {

      myREBMIX[[i, j, k]] <- REBMIX(Dataset = list(galaxy),
        Preprocessing = Preprocessing[k], D = 0.0025,
        cmax = 12, Criterion = InformationCriterion[j],
        pdf = pdf[i], K = K[[k]])
      if (is.null(Table)) {
        Table <- myREBMIX[[i, j, k]]@summary
      } else {
        Table <- merge(Table, myREBMIX[[i, j,k]]@summary, all = TRUE, sort = FALSE)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is late. But I encountered a similar problem just a few minutes ago. And I realized the real scenario that you may face when you got this kind of error msg... It's just the **version conflict**.

You may use a different version of the R package from the tutorial, thus the argument names could be different between what you are running and what the real code use.

So please **check the version first** before you try to manually edit the file. Also, it happens that your old version package is still in the path and it overrides the new one. This was exactly what I had... since I manually installed the old and new version separately...